# Setting restricted segments in network using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-network-analysis

I am trying to set up a network with QGIS. When I set the direction field there are three options for the values in that field:

- Forward direction
- Backward direction
- Both directions

but I need to set some segments of the network as restricted. I have tried with the QGIS Processing network analysis tools and with QNEAT3 plugin, but I can't find an option to restrict some segments.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you adjust the time value (in case of fastest path optimization) to a very high value or simply remove the edge from the graph?

Comment: I forgot to mention how I'm doing... For now I'm disconnecting the forbidden edges and, if at any time they stop being forbidden, I can reconnect them.